# Insert document to a collection with mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I need to insert a document into mongodb without using the models, just raw documents without following a model. I'm currently doing the following:

```
db.analyticsNew.insert(documents_list)
```

But this throws an error saying

> AttributeError: 'MongoEngine' object has no attribute 'analyticsNew'

From what I know, I think it can't find the mentioned collection. But the collection exists in the db. Plus, even if this collection isn't there, it should create one.

Any ideas as to whats wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: *MongoEngine is an Object-Document Mapper, written in Python for working with MongoDB*. Use pymongo if you dont want to work with models. Here is [pymongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html)

Comment: So you're saying there's no way to achieve what I'm trying to using mongoengine? The thing is this is not a learning exercise or something like that. It's a company's product and I can't change the tools and technologies just like that. I have to use mongoengine

Comment: Then I guess you have to work with models, I can't see any way to run raw queries with mongoengine. Maybe there is but I couldn't see.

Comment: alright. I get it now. I'll create the models then.

Comment: Also, if you can put that info in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MongoEngine is a Document-Object Mapper (think ORM, but for document
>   databases) for working with MongoDB from Python.

That means you have to work with models which are python classes each represents a mongo collection.

If you need to run raw queries you may think to use [pymongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

MongoEngine is built on top of pymongo. It exposes pymongo and therefore you can use it for raw queries as well.

For instance have a look at [this](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#raw-queries).